# proof that every sentence obtainable by left-most derivations only when Greibach normal form

Tags: automata, context-free, normal-forms, derivation

Could someone help me prove the following statement:
“For any grammar in Greibach normal form, every sentence is obtainable by left-most derivations only.”
I see that this is trivial, but I can't manage to start a formal proof of this statement.

What I thought is:
Since every derivation in Greibach Normal Form has a form of A -> aX or
A -> a
with 'a' being a terminal and X being 0 or more variables, we can see that going from left to right we can get each terminal 'b' of the string by taking the corresponding production rule with B -> bY.
I think that whatever grammar it is, we can always say that every sentence is obtainable by left-most derivations and also by right-most derivations.

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are simply the statement of an exercise-style task (and perhaps a statement that you don't know how to get started).  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W. I updated the question, sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the grammar is in Greibach Normal Form does not contribute to the assertion being proved. For any context-free grammar $G$ with start symbol $S$, $\omega\in L(G)\iff S\Rightarrow_{lm}^*\omega$. It's not necessary to restrict the syntax of the productions of $G$ beyond the restriction imposed by the context-free restraint (which is that there is exactly a single non-terminal on the left-hand side of every production).

An essential observation about context-free grammars is that it doesn't matter which order you expand the non-terminals in a sentential form. (That's the origin of the description "context-free".) Regardless of which non-terminal you expand, you will end up with the same set of possible sentential forms and therefore the same set of sentences.

There are a number of ways to prove this simple statement, but I think the easiest is probably to use parse trees as an intermediate representation. A derivation is precisely a topological ordering of the non-leaf nodes in the parse tree. Unless the tree is linear, there are many such orderings, but since they all end with the same sentence, the tree is capturing an equivalence relationship less evident in the collection of derivations. With the parse tree in hand, it's easy to show that the leftmost derivation is the preorder left-to-right depth-first traverse of the tree, while the rightmost derivation is the preorder right-to-left depth-first traverse. Consequently, there is a unique left-most derivation corresponding to each parse tree (as well as a unique right-most derivation), which proves the original assertion.

Filling in the details in this proof outline is exercise 24 in section 5.1 of Peter Linz's *An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata* (in the old edition I managed to find); it is not marked with a star so I guess the author considers it relatively easy to complete.